# Improve the speed of my bash code

Tags: performance, bash

The following is the file format I need to deal with:

```
@HWI-ST150_0129:2:1:4226:2616#0/1
CATCTTTTCTCTTAACTTCCATGATGGTACATCTTTTGATTTTTTTTTAATAACGTCTTTGACAGCTTAAATTCTTTTTCAAAATC
+HWI-ST150_0129:2:1:4226:2616#0/1
d\dddddaddbcad^\^a\]ZZZ_`]\VYa_bZ^_^\YX\X`eeeeffffffefffeeefffefffeeffBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Basically what I need to do is:
1.pick out every 4th line; and trim all possible trailing "B" at the END of the string.

2.If the left part is > 70% of the whole string after the trimming, then: trim the counterpart in every 2nd line for the trainling "B" in 4th line.

3.Then just append all 4 lines with 2nd and 4th trimmed.

So the expected result is as follows:

```
@HWI-ST150_0129:2:1:4226:2616#0/1
CATCTTTTCTCTTAACTTCCATGATGGTACATCTTTTGATTTTTTTTTAATAACGTCTTTGACAGCTTAA
+HWI-ST150_0129:2:1:4226:2616#0/1
d\dddddaddbcad^\^a\]ZZZ_`]\VYa_bZ^_^\YX\X`eeeeffffffefffeeefffefffeeff
```

And I wrote a script like:

```
for((a=1;a<=8000000;a++))
do
  if (($a%4==0))
  then  
      b=`cat $FILENAME|head -$a|tail -1|sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g'|wc -c`
      d=`cat $FILENAME|head -$a|tail -1|wc -c`
      if (( 10*$b/$d>= 7 ))
      then
          cat $FILENAME|head -$(($a-3))|tail -1
          cat $FILENAME|head -$(($a-2))|tail -1|cut -b 1-$(($b-1))
          cat $FILENAME|head -$(($a-1))|tail -1
          cat $FILENAME|head -$a|tail -1|sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g'
      fi
  fi
done >> /home/xxx/$DIRNAME/$FILENAME
```

I think I prefer bash code, simply because it's fast (?). However when I run this code, it's slow when thinking about 8000000 lines to go. Also, maybe I've used "cat" too much in the code?

by fast, I mean, say, when using split commands to split GB-level large file; it's super super fast. (What's the mechanism of split?)

Any suggestions to improve the speed?

Comment: You dont need cat at all in this script.  head, tail, sed and wc all take a filename as an argument.  You can just `head -... $FILENAME | tail -1 | cut.....`. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html ;).  Also, this may be a better question for the code review stackexchange site.

Comment: I agree with @chown. `cat` isn't really needed when you are just piping the output to `head`.

Comment: Thanks guys. yeah you are right. So maybe "cat" is rate-limiting factor...

Comment: Yea, cause if you think about it, if you file has 800,000 lines, then `cat` peruses all of those just to pipe it to `head` which then fetches say top 10 of the lines. Simpler way would be to just do `head` on the file to stop perusing after 10 lines.

Comment: @Jaypal: `head` will exit after 10 lines, breaking the pipe, so `cat` won't read more than somewhat over 10 lines.

Comment: @Chris, Sorry I didn't quite follow your suggestion?

Comment: @Jaypal: You claimed that `cat` will read all lines before piping them to `head`. That is not true. `cat` will read one line, (or really it will fill a buffer of X bytes, but i'm simplifying, bear with me) then write that one line to `head`. Then it will read another line, and write that line to `head`, and so on. When `head` has read 10 lines, it will exit, which will send SIGPIPE to `cat` and terminate it long before all the lines have been read. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE

Comment: Thanks Chris. I wasn't aware of that. Good Info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your logic so it works like this:

1) Read in 4 lines.

2) Process the 4 lines you read in.

3) Write out the results of your processing

4) Repeat.

Your code goes through the file six times on each pass. You only need to go through it once for everything.

Answer (score 1):

I think part of the problem may be that every iteration of the outmost for loop, you're going to be catting/heading/whatevering the entire text file...which I would imagine would be the source of the bottleneck.

Removing the cat probably won't make it much faster, since you're calling those other unix commands on it every time.

You might want to look for a solution that can just read the file once and produce the necessary output, rather than reading it 8,000,000 * 6 times. (1 vs. 48,000,000! :) )

Here's the idea:

```
f = OPEN_FILE() //Some file descriptor
out_f = NEW_FILE_FOR_WRITING() //open some file to write to
while not_eof(f):
    cur_window = read_four_lines(f) //Get four lines from the text thing
    modified_block = do_stuff(cur_window) //Do your processing in a different function
    write(out_f,modified_block) //Write the modified stuff to the output file
```

I'm not sure what language you're most comfortable with, but this shouldn't be too difficult  to do. I'd imagine it's possible in a bash script, with a few modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `~` to make changes to every 4th line with `sed`. If your intention is to trim all trailing B on every 4th line of your INPUT_FILE then simply do -

For example:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

[jaypal:~/Temp] sed '0~4 s/[0-9]/bbbb/' file
1
2
3
bbbb
5
6
7
bbbb
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

David is right. It is really inefficient to parse the same big file more than one time. Also, invoking all those external programs is killing performance too.

Here is a simple implementation of the logic provided by David in bash with only one external command per loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
DONE=false
until $DONE ; do
read -r LINE1 || DONE=true
read -r LINE2 || DONE=true
read -r LINE3 || DONE=true
read -r LINE4 || DONE=true

NEWLINE4=`echo $LINE4 |sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g'`
NEWLINE2=${LINE2:0:${#NEWLINE4}}

echo $LINE1
echo $NEWLINE2
echo $LINE3
echo $NEWLINE4

done
```

It is very simple and has some gotchas (it prints 4 empty lines at the end) that are easily fixable. This code should be many times quicker than your first version.